# select with css only one button by id

Tags: html, css

How to select with css only one button by id?

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button class="btn" id="playBtn">play</button>
    <button class="btn" id="pauseBtn">pause</button>                
</div>
```

I tried `#playBtn{}`, `button #playBtn{}`, `#buttons #playBtn{}`, `#buttons button #playBtn{}`

Comment: `#playBtn {}` should work just fine.

Comment: `button #playBtn` would mean an element with ID `playBtn` which is a descendant of a button element. I guess you meant `button#playBtn` (no space), which means a button element which also has an ID of `playBtn`. But as mentioned in one answer, there is no need to do that, since the element can be uniquely identified just as `#playBtn`.

Comment: Something else to note: It is a good to remember certain css styles do not work with certain HTML elements as one expects: Such as a `Block`, `Inline-Block` and `Inline`. Certain CSS properties fail from one type to another. [MORE FOUND HERE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using id then you don't really need to mess around with different specificities - there is only one element on the page that you can possibly be trying to target. Therefore `#playBtn` {} is fine

Comment: My problem was in order of css styles.  Than your for reasuring me!

Comment: How would order of css styles affect the interpretation of `#playBtn`?

Comment: I don't know but it does. Maybe it has something to do with button{} styles that could affect buttons in some way. Or maybe it's because of styles for .textar {} some dynamically appending textareas..